# Segmentation fault using fgets in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm

I tried to read an input into a buffer with fgets. I pushed the 3 parameters, but got segmentation fault. I tried to see the problem with GDB, but I didn't understand the message that I got there.
This is the code:

```
section .rodata
    buffer: db 10
section .text
    align 16 
    global main 
    extern fgets 
    extern stdin  
main: 
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp    
    pushad              
    push dword[stdin] 
    push 10;
    push buffer;
    call fgets;
    add esp, 12
    popad           
    mov esp, ebp    
    pop ebp
    ret
```

And this is the message that I got:

```
       Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
       __GI__IO_getline_info (fp=fp@entry=0xf7fb1c20 <_IO_2_1_stdin_>,
       buf=buf@entry=0x80484f0 "\n", n=8, n@entry=9, delim=delim@entry=10,
       extract_delim=extract_delim@entry=1, eof=eof@entry=0x0) at            iogetline.c:86
       86      iogetline.c: No such file or directory.
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Your `buffer`is in read only data section `.rodata` . Place it in `.data` instead. The segfault occurs trying to write to read only area of memory.

Comment: Also `db 10` will allocate a single byte with value `10`, not 10 bytes as you probably want.

Comment: Actually, place it in the `.bss` section and use `resb 10` to reserve 10 bytes.  Your current version is one byte, initialized to `{ 10 }`.  You don't want to store a bunch of zeros in your executable for no reason; that's what the bss is for.

Comment: Peter is correct, you can place it in `.bss` and use `resb 10`. If you did want to put it in `.data` you could allocate it with zeroes with something like `buffer: times 10 db 0`. Alternatively you could place the buffer on the stack by reserving memory for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You segfault because you ask `fgets` to write to an address in the `.rodata` section.  It's of course read-only.

Put your buffer in the `.bss` section, and use `resb 10` to reserve 10 bytes.  Your current version is one byte, initialized to `{ 10 }`.  You don't want to store a bunch of zeros in your executable for no reason; that's what the bss is for.

```
section .bss
    buffer: resb 10
    buffer_length equ $ - buffer
section .text
    align 16 
    global main 
    extern fgets 
    extern stdin  
main: 
    push dword [stdin]
    push buffer_length
    push buffer           ; 3 pushes gets the stack back to 16B-alignment
    call fgets
    add esp, 12
    ret
```

You don't need `pusha`, or a stack frame (the stuff with ebp) in this function.  Normally you only save/restore call-preserved registers you want to use, not all of them every time.

As Michael Petch points out, it would also be better to reserve space on the stack for the buffer, instead of using static storage.  Have a look at compiler output for an equivalent C function that uses a local array.  (e.g. on http://gcc.godbolt.org/).